# Can a cop direct a pharmacist to fill a known fraudulent prescription in order to convict a subject of a higher crime?

Tags: criminal-law, human-rights, constitutional-law, process, sentencing

If a cop is responding to a **known** fraudulent prescription, ask the pharmacist to stall the subject until they arrive so he can arrest the subject, but, instead of making the arrest for attempt to obtain by fraud, directs the pharmacist to fill the **known** fraudulent prescription in order to arrest the subject for the higher crime of trafficking, is the subject guilty of possession/trafficking?

If the subject is not guilty of possession then the subject can get up to 5 years in prison for an attempt or qualify for drug court:

> Florida Statutes 893.13 (7)(a)9
>   Acquire or obtain, or attempt to acquire or obtain, possession of a controlled substance by misrepresentation, fraud, forgery, deception, or subterfuge.

If the subject is guilty of possession, most hydrocodone prescriptions will consist of an aggregate trafficking amount, then the subject is disqualified for drug court and faces an ***extremely severe penalty***:

> Florida Statutes 893.135 1(c)1c
>   Is 28 grams or more, but less than 30 kilograms, such person shall be sentenced to a *mandatory minimum term of imprisonment of 25 years and shall be ordered to pay a fine of $500,000*.

It seems the same as a cop planting drugs on someone to convict them of possession or trafficking.

Comment: If you're a pharmacist, don't you have a certification and code of ethics that would dictate what you should do?

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes, there are federal/state laws as well as pharmacy procedures that a pharmacist must abide by in order to keep their license. The cop directed the pharmacist to bypass all of them to put the subject in possession

Comment: **other than one who is ready to commit it**. *You can arguably say a person can not be ready to commit a crime if there is a law in place to prevent that crime from occurring.* Yeah, you could argue that if you like to lose. I mean, you could open with that, but now you need to back it up with facts about the accused.

Comment: Your assertions - particularly that last one - are dangerous and should not be relied upon in any circumstances where their accuracy is desirable. It is reckless to spread and assert this opinion - and then accept your own answer - without evidence to support it. Statutory interpretation is a skill learned through years of practice, and reinforced - or disproven - by case law. Please, cite some case law that supports your various arguments within the _rationes_. ***You have accepted your own erroneous answer - if you had any interest in justice you would accept another answer and delete it.***

Comment: @jimsug show me in the law where it says a police officer can direct a pharmacist to break federal and state laws and fill a known fraudulent prescription

Comment: Moreover, show me in the law where it is completed fraud when the plaintiff is aware of the falsity of the representation

Comment: @Breakwater Where in 893.135(1)c does it say anything about fraud?

Comment: @cpast, I've updated the question. The fraud statute is 893.13 (7)(a)9, but if guilty of possession the subject also gets charged with 893.135(1)(c)1c

Comment: @Breakskater But those are different statutes. 7a9 has clearly been violated, because it says "if you get drugs through fraud **or try to do so**, you're going to jail" (as for "is attempt literally the same as completed and is reliance an element," I'd leave that to an actual lawyer who knows Florida criminal drug laws). But that has no bearing on the more serious charge. 1c1c doesn't require fraud, just purchase/possession, and those were certainly present, so the elements of 1c1c are met.

Comment: @cpast I agree the subject is guilty of 7a9 because of `attempt to acquire`.  The subject made an attempt relying on the misrepresentation. 7a9 makes a distinction between attempt and acquire. It was just an attempt up until a particular point in time. Everyone agrees with that. The subject was predisposed to possess by fraud, not by cop. After acquired, we have 1c1c and it is irrefutable that the cop caused the acquiring. So far, you have been the closest to a defense: there are missing elements to complete obtaining by fraud which subject relied and the subject is only guilty of attempt 7a9

Comment: @Breakskater Now I think you're just mashing terms together. Fraud is *not an element* of 1c1c. In order to claim the prosecution didn't show an element of a crime, you first need it to be an actual element of the crime. 1c1c has only four elements: defendant knowingly purchased/possessed the drug, the drug was one of the things on the list, there was at least 4 grams of the drug, and (for the enhancement) there was between 28 and 30000 grams of the drug. Nowhere there does it say there needs to be fraud; the charge applies just as well to deals in an alley. So, no missing element there.

Comment: @cpast we do need to consider the elements of fraud because 1c1c refers back to 893.13 (7)(a)9 `Except as authorized in this chapter or in chapter 499 and notwithstanding the provisions of s. 893.13:` which describes how a person can possess without authorization: 893.13 (7)(a)9 in this case. The missing obtaining by fraud element is plaintiffs (cop and pharmacist) awareness of the falsity of the script so the subject is only guilty of 7a9 correct?

Comment: What do you think "notwithstanding" means?

Comment: @cpast The language is confusing but the verbiage was written to harmonize the two laws and exclude any duplication of penalties between 893.135 and 893.13, not to eliminate defenses; therefore, we still have the elements of possession by fraud - [O'HARA v State](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=13973505031795780418&q=notwithstanding+the+provisions+of+s.+893.13+florida&hl=en&as_sdt=4,10)

Comment: "harmonize the laws and exclude duplication of penalties" -- No, "notwithstanding" means the *exact opposite* of that. It means "ignore this other law when looking at the meaning of the current one."

Comment: @cpast review the cited case. If you exclude 893.13, then it means anyone, even with a valid prescription, who possesses amounts of controlled substances declared in 893.135 would be guilty of trafficking. That's not why the passage was added

Comment: No. Because it says "except as authorized by this chapter or chapter 499." Neither chapter says it's OK to have a controlled substance as long as you didn't have it by fraud.

Comment: @cpast that's exactly my point. Possessing the controlled substance has to be authorized by those chapters, including 893.135 in which fraud is an unauthorized possession of a controlled substance

Comment: Here is an interesting question that comes to mind if the cop authorized the filling and pharmacist filled it, then will that make the subject's possession authorized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29734/discussion-between-cpast-and-breakskater).

Answer (score 10):

The circuits all over the place on this one but I don't see these facts fitting according to the strictest rule.

> It is within the discretion of the police to decide whether delaying
>   the arrest of the suspect will help ensnare co-conspirators, as
>   exemplified by this case, will give the police greater understanding
>   of the nature of the criminal enterprise, **or merely will allow the
>   suspect enough "rope to hang himself**."

*U.S. V. Garcia* 79 F.3d 74 (7th Cir. 1996)

See also  *Hoffa v. United States* 385 U.S. 293 (1966)

> A suspect has no constitutional right to be arrested when the police
>   have probable cause.
>
> The police are not required to guess, at their peril, the precise
>   moment at which they have probable cause to arrest a suspect, risking
>   a violation of the Fourth Amendment if they act too soon, and a
>   violation of the Sixth Amendment if they wait too long. Law
>   enforcement officers are under no constitutional duty to call a halt
>   to a criminal investigation the moment they have the minimum evidence
>   to establish probable cause, a quantum of evidence which may fall far
>   short of the amount necessary to support a criminal conviction.

**EDITING THE ANSWER in light of some comments.**

Florida recognizes sentence manipulation and outrageous government conduct as defenses. *United States v. Ciszkowski*, 492 F.3d 1264, 1270 (11th Cir. 2007) Outrageous government conduct and sentencing factor manipulation focus on the government's behavior. Outrageous government conduct occurs when law enforcement obtains a conviction for conduct **beyond the defendant's predisposition** by employing methods that fail to comport with due process guarantees. Under this standard, the conduct must be so outrageous that it is fundamentally unfair. See *United States v. Ofshe*, 817 F.2d 1508, 1516 (11th Cir.1987)

In the Ciszkowski case, the defendant was charged with murder for hire as part of a sting. As part of the sting, the government provided Ciszkowski with the gun. The gun had a silencer, the silencer converted his crime to a more serious offense. Ciszkowski argued that he did not know the gun had a silencer and accused the government of sentence manipulation. He lost. The court tells us that the standard for establishing that the government's conduct is **sufficiently reprehensible** to constitute sentencing factor manipulation is high as gives us some cases where the court declined the finding.

See *United States v. Bohannon*, 476 F.3d 1246, 1252 (11th Cir.2007 (government's selection of age of "minor" victim for sting operation was not manipulation even though the selected age resulted in enhancement under guideline);

*United States v. Williams*, 456 F.3d 1353, 1370-71 (11th Cir.2006) government's purchase of crack cocaine rather than powder cocaine was not manipulation despite sentencing differential);

*United States v. Sanchez*, 138 F.3d 1410, 1412-13 (11th Cir.1998) (government informant's selection of a fictitious amount of drugs to be stolen by defendants was not manipulation of the quantity)

Now, about this doctor. The reason this is might be troubling is that this doctor might have entrapped the suspect. For example, if the suspect went to the dr and just wanted some aspirin but the dr convinced him to ask for vicodin and pain killers in some excessive amount (I don't know, I do not want to make up facts). This could be entrapment by a citizen acting purely on his own; if this is the case there is no entrapment. See  *Worley v. State*, 848 So. 2d 491 (Fla. Dist. Ct. App. 2003)

However, when the person making the inducement is acting as an agent of the government, courts may allow an entrapment defense. **The government is responsible for the actions of its agents.** But keep in mind that you still need to establish both elements of entrapment.

Per *United States v. Isnadin*, No. 12-13474 (Feb. 12, 2014):

> The entrapment defense involves two separate elements : (1) Government
>   inducement of the crime, and (2) lack of predisposition on the part of
>   the defendant. The defendant bears an initial burden of production to
>   show that the first element, Government inducement, is met. Once the
>   defendant makes this initial showing, the burden shifts to the
>   Government to prove beyond a reasonable doubt that the **defendant was
>   predisposed to commit the crime**.

For any of these defenses to work, the guy who was filling the prescription can not have been predisposed to commit the crime except for the actions of the government and its agents inducing him.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99266/discussion-on-answer-by-jqning-can-a-cop-direct-a-pharmacist-to-fill-a-known-fra).