# Are law enforcement officers obliged to apprehend a subject committing a crime at the earliest possible opportunity?

Tags: united-states, police, arrest

Inspired in part by [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/3643/58): if a person is committing crimes of increasing severity, are law enforcement personnel obliged to apprehend them at the earliest opportunity? Specifically, are they obliged to prevent a crime at the stage where it is a [conspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_(criminal)), or [attempt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attempt), to commit it?

If so, in what circumstances?

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider only US cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circuits all over the place on this one but in short, no, **police are not obliged to apprehend a suspect at the earliest opportunity**.

> It is within the discretion of the police to decide whether delaying
>   the arrest of the suspect will help ensnare co-conspirators, as
>   exemplified by this case, will give the police greater understanding
>   of the nature of the criminal enterprise, **or merely will allow the
>   suspect enough "rope to hang himself**."

*U.S. V. Garcia* 79 F.3d 74 (7th Cir. 1996)

See also  *Hoffa v. United States* 385 U.S. 293 (1966)

> A suspect has no constitutional right to be arrested when the police
>   have probable cause.
>
> The police are not required to guess, at their peril, the precise
>   moment at which they have probable cause to arrest a suspect, risking
>   a violation of the Fourth Amendment if they act too soon, and a
>   violation of the Sixth Amendment if they wait too long. Law
>   enforcement officers are under no constitutional duty to call a halt
>   to a criminal investigation the moment they have the minimum evidence
>   to establish probable cause, a quantum of evidence which may fall far
>   short of the amount necessary to support a criminal conviction.